# How can I check the provider status ? if testRPC connected or not?

Tags: web3js, testrpc, ethereumjs, api-design

I have a problem with using : *web3.net.listening* 
The case when I am connected to the testRPC is working and it returns me TRUE.
But the case I am not connected it returns me INTERNAL SERVER ERROR.
I understand that this "listening" object doesn't exist when I am no longuer connected to testRPC.
**How can I solve this? so I can get false as result if testrpc not connected.**

```
const config = require('config');
const Router = require('koa-router');
const router = new Router();

const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3();
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider(config.provider.url));

router.get('/cbn/provider-status', ctx => {

    const listening = web3.net.listening;
    if (listening){
        ctx.body = {"status":listening}
    }
    else ctx.body = {"status":"false"}

})
```

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use web3.isConnected() to check if connection to node exists or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer for that issue:

```
router.get('/cbn/provider-status', ctx => {
    ctx.body = {"status":web3.isConnected()}
})
```